# How can I display an array in HTML so that numbers are broken into new line

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display an array in HTML so that the displayed integers are broken into a new line.  The JS is breaking them into a new line, yes, but when the numbers are single number like from 0 - 9, they don't break into a new line.  The numbers that break into a new line only start from double digit ie. 10 going upwards.

Here is my JS code:  I think there is something wrong with the FOR LOOP in  the function displayArray, but I just cant figure it out.  This is one of the final pieces to almost tie this up!

Thanking you in advance for any contributions!

```
//Array to hold statistics of number of pages read per sitting  over a period of time
const myArray = [];
//Function to calculate number of pages read
let calculate = () => {
  var start = document.getElementById("number1").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("number2").value;
  document.getElementById("number1").value = ""; // make START empty
  document.getElementById("number2").value = ""; //make END empty
  let totalNumber = end - start; 
  myArray.push(totalNumber); //Push total number into array
  document.getElementById("congrats").textContent =
    "Congrats, you read " + totalNumber + "  pages today!";//display message
  document.getElementById("rightpane").textContent = myArray;//push array into HTML

  displayArray();//Call display array

};

//Function to display myARRAY broken down to a new line
const displayArray = ()=> {
  let displayedNumbers='';
  for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){

       displayedNumbers += myArray[i] + "\n";
  };  
  document.getElementById("rightpane").textContent = displayedNumbers;//Append myArray into HTML
}
```

Comment: This is weird, I am just discovering that the array only breaks into a new line in mobile width, but when I expand my screen to desktop that does not happen at all

Comment: I also tried <br>, does not work

Comment: is it possible to add a screen shot here?

Comment: @MisterJojo, kindly provide a code snippet do that I can see what you mean

Answer (score 1):

Append a prefixed 0 to any number less than 10

Comment: Good idea, let me try that, but how do I start!

Comment: an IF statement maybe?

Comment: It would be with an if statement, however i believe you will need to at least swap the data type to a string to prefix the zero in. I haven't had my coffee yet but if i figure it out ill post it up for you

Answer (score 0):

You could append a number to the start of the list item and increase it by one each time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, but if you want numbers to appear in new line without using lists and CSS you can wrap them in 'pre' tags and it should break it to new row like this:

```js
displayArray();

function displayArray(){
myArray = [0,1,2,3,4];

  let displayedNumbers='';
  for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
       displayedNumbers += "<pre>"+myArray[i] + "</pre>";
  };  
  document.getElementById("rightpane").innerHTML = displayedNumbers;//Append myArray into HTML
}
```

```css
#rightpane{
background : #000;
height : 200px;
width: 100px;
color:white;
padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<pre>0</pre><pre>1</pre><pre>2</pre><pre>3</pre>





<div id="rightpane"></div>
```

Comment: An issue I am having now is that when the numbers are displayed in my HTML div they appear with <pre>1</pre>.

How can I get rid of <pre> so that I see numbers only?

Answer (score 0):

I have just made your code some corrections...

and adding **parseInt**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

and you also have to look at `white-space: pre`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

```
// Array to hold statistics of number of pages read per sitting  over a period of time
const myArray = []
    , Num_1     = document.getElementById('number1')
    , Num_2     = document.getElementById('number2')
    , congrats  = document.getElementById("congrats")
    , rightpane = document.getElementById("rightpane")

const LeadZeros =(val,lg)=>('0'.repeat(lg)+val).slice(-lg)

// Function to calculate number of pages read
const calculate =_=>
{
  let totalNumber = parseInt(Num_2.value) - parseInt(Num_1.value)

  Num_1.value = '' // make START empty
  Num_2.value = '' // make END empty

  myArray.push( LeadZeros(totalNumber,3) ) // Push total number into array
/*
// or:
myArray.push( totalNumber.toString(10).padStart(3, '0') )
*/

  congrats.textContent  = `Congrats, you read ${totalNumber} pages today!` // display message
  rightpane.textContent = myArray.join("\n")   // push array into HTML
}
```

I also remove your function **DisplayArray()** and use **Array.join()** method .
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

**leadZero** function use :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/repeat
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/slice

leadZero is divided into two parts: (for example lg = 3)

**1)** '0'.repeat (3) + val ===' 000 '+ val
    if val = 5  it gives   '0005'
    if val = 42 this gives '00042'

**nota:** the first value is a *string* and force the setting in value string too

**2)** () .slice (-lg) <=> () .slice (-3)
   when we put a negative value the method string.slice pars the last character and goes up (from 3 here)

the last 3 characters of:
  '0005'.slice(-3)  => '005'
  '00042'.slice(-3) => '042'

Comment: Thanks @Mister Jojo thats some awesome code, but I still go back to the original error where single numbers from the array result  do not break into a new line, numbers that break into new line start from 10.  How can a prepend zeroes to single integers so that they appear like 001, 002, 003  etc?

I think this will solve my problem

Comment: something like this:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-JavaScript

Comment: thanks for taking me this far, I will try to read around on how I can append the lead zeroes, I am sure it can be done with effort.

Comment: @Chris  I added helpful comments on my post. Do not forget to validate my answer?

Comment: how do I validate? I am still relatively new on this platform as I rarely use it.  Just tell me how and I will do it.

Comment: its now working!  But this Javascript code is too complicated for me to understand how some parts work, especially the LeadZero. Can I still use it in my app?  Now my fear is that if I do use it as it is and put it into my portfolio when I am later asked about it I won't be able to explain it.

Comment: @Chris I added more explanation about LeadZero -- I just discovered myself you can use startPad method =>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: @Chris for validation:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Okay let me take a look

Comment: When I try to upvote your answer  the counter does not accept my upvote, I guess I haven't yet amassed enough reputation

Comment: @Chris But you can **validate** my answer (not upvote) ( and this give you some reputation points)